# Object-oriented design for comment subject object

Tags: java, json, oop, enums

I'm trying to figure out the best way to design a class, which encapsulates JSON-derived comments. Each comment is targeted at a particular subject, either a file as a whole or a line of a file. Here's an example comment:

```
{
    "text":"This is my favorite line!",
    "path":"My file.txt",
    "line":42
    ...
}
```

If the subject is a file as a whole, `line` is `null`.

I want the `Comment` class to have a `subject()` method, but I'm not sure the best way to design the `CommentSubject` class. Here's what I have so far:

```
import javax.json.JsonObject;

class Comment {
    private final JsonObject json;
    private final CommentSubject subject;

    public JsonObject json() { return json; }
    public CommentSubject subject() { return subject; }

    public Comment(JsonObject json) {
        ...
        this.json = json;
        subject = json.isNull("line") ? new FileSubject(this) :
            new LineSubject(this);
        ...
    }

    ...
}

abstract class CommentSubject {
    enum SubjectType {
        FILE, LINE
    }

    public abstract SubjectType type();
    public abstract String path();
    protected abstract Comment comment();
}

class FileSubject extends CommentSubject {
    private final Comment comment;
    private final String path;

    public FileSubject(Comment comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
        path = comment.json().getString("path");
    }

    public FileSubject(CommentSubject subject) {
        this(subject.comment());
    }

    @Override public SubjectType type() { return SubjectType.FILE; }
    @Override public String path() { return path; }
    @Override protected Comment comment() { return comment; }

    ...
}

class LineSubject extends CommentSubject {
    private final Comment comment;
    private final String path;
    private final int line;

    public LineSubject(Comment comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
        path = comment.json().getString("path");
        line = comment.json().getInt("line");
    }

    public LineSubject(CommentSubject subject) {
        this(subject.comment());
    }

    @Override public SubjectType type() { return SubjectType.LINE; }
    @Override public String path() { return path; }
    @Override protected Comment comment() { return comment; }

    public int line() { return line; }

    ...
}
```

Client code could look like this:

```
doSomething(CommentSubject subject) {
    if (subject.type() == SubjectType.LINE) {
        LineSubject line = new LineSubject(subject);
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

However, I don't like the fact that my current design requires a new `LineSubject` object in the client code: `subject` and `line` are identical in the example above, so the new object creation seems like a waste of space. Further, in order to pass a `CommentSubject` object to another `CommentSubject` constructor, as in the client code above, all subjects need to be backed by a comment accessible by the `comment()` method. I also don't know what I think about the `SubjectType` `enum`.

What I want is for `Comment` to have a `subject()` method and to be able to distinguish file and line subjects. Are there better designs out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only difference between a file comment and a line comment is that the file comment does not have a line number, you can fold the class hierarchy to a single class, and make the line number optional (i.e. returning an `Integer` rather than an `int`). This would let client programs distinguish between file and line comments, because file comments would return `null` for the line number:

```
public class CommentSubject {

    private final Integer line;
    private final String path;
    private final String comment;

    public String path() { return path; }
    public Integer line() { return line; }
    public Comment comment() { return comment; }

    public static CommentSubject forFile(String p, String c) {
        return new CommentSubject(p, null, c);
    }
    public static CommentSubject forLine(String p, int i, String c) {
        return new CommentSubject(p, i, c);
    }

    private CommentSubject(String p, Integer i, String c) {
        path = p;
        line = i;
        comment = c;
    }
}
```

The client would be able to write something like this:

```
doSomething(CommentSubject subject) {
    Integer optLine = subject.line();
    if (optLine != null) {
        int line = optLine.intValue();
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

If you prefer to avoid conditional dispatch in the client, you could take a visitor-like approach, and have the `CommentSubject` call back the processor of your comments, like this:

```
interface CommentProcessor {
    void onFileComment(String path, String comment);
    void onLineComment(String path, int line, String comment);
}
public class CommentSubject {

    private final Integer line;
    private final String path;
    private final String comment;

    public void process(CommentProcessor p) {
        if (line != null) {
            p.onLineComment(path, line.intValue(), comment);
        } else {
            p.onFileComment(path, comment);
        }
    }

    public static CommentSubject forFile(String p, String c) {
        return new CommentSubject(p, null, c);
    }
    public static CommentSubject forLine(String p, int i, String c) {
        return new CommentSubject(p, i, c);
    }

    private CommentSubject(String p, Integer i, String c) {
        path = p;
        line = i;
        comment = c;
    }
}
```

Note how the comment, path, and line are hidden inside `CommentSubject`. The only way to access them now is to pass an instance of `CommentProcessor`, which would receive a callback for the appropriate type of `CommentSubject`.